# Proof verification: Prove or disaprove that for any group V, there is a field K such that V/K is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

Here is my proof that the proposition in the title is false (disaproval). Is everything alright with it? My professor told me to rewrite it.

Here goes:

We will be using $(Z,+)$ as the group and $(K,+,*)$ as the field, where $K$ is an arbitrary set.

$Z = <1> \rightarrow dim_{k}Z = 1$

Also $dim_{k}K = 1$, so $dim_{k}Z = dim_{k}K \rightarrow Z \simeq K$ as vector spaces, thus $Z \simeq K$ as groups.

Suppose there exists a "*" rule such that $(Z,+,*)$ is a field.

We note $1*1 = \alpha$ and $e_{\alpha}$ the neutral element respective to "*" rule.

$e_{\alpha} * x = x$

$e_{\alpha} * x * 1 * 1 = e_{\alpha} * \alpha$

From the last two we have $x = e_{\alpha} * x * \alpha \rightarrow e_{\alpha} * \alpha = 1$

We further have that $e_{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha} \rightarrow \alpha = \pm 1$

But for both $1 * 1 = 1$ and $1 * 1 = -1$, $(Z,+,*)$ is not a field, thus we end up with a contradiction. This ends my proof that you can't find a field for any group such that the two form a vector space.

Comment: Your question is unclear: what is the construction $V/K$? It seems that you're considering $Z$ to already be a $K$-vector space, since you're writing $\mathrm{dim}_K Z$.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/prove-mathbbz-is-not-a-vector-space-over-a-field?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781784/prove-that-mathbbz-is-not-isomorphic-to-additive-group-of-any-vector-space?rq=1