# Show that Z cannot be turned into a vector space over any field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, characteristic-functions

Show that Z cannot be turned into a vector space over any field.

So, we have 2 cases here.

Case 1:lets suppose the charF=P,

n does not equal 0, then (1+1+...+1)n=1n+1n+...+1n=n+n+...+n=pn=wchich does not equal zero

=0n

=0               ................................................           a contradiction

Case 2: CharF=0 ->Q

?????

Comment: Consider the element $\frac 1 2 $ in your field.

Comment: (As a furhter hint, the element $x=\frac 1 2\cdot 1\in\Bbb Z$ would have the property that $x+x=1$.)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/prove-mathbbz-is-not-a-vector-space-over-a-field?rq=1.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a vector space over the field of 1 element.

Comment: @oxeimon Would you prefer impaling, flaying, stoning...?

Comment: I suppose if the stones were coming from the field of 1 element, I'd only get hit once, so I'd be okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Bbb Z$ were a vector space over some field $F$, then it must be a 1-dimensional vector space, since $\Bbb Z$ is generated as an additive group by 1. Now simply note that $\Bbb Z$ is not a field.