# is $\mathbb R$ a subspace of $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: linear-algebra

As far as I know, a subspace have to satisfy $3$ conditions.

1. $\mathbb R$ of course has a null vector.
2. Two instances of $\mathbb R$, let's say $r_1$ and $r_2$, satisfy that $r_1+r_2$ belongs to $\mathbb R$ itself.
3. For any instance from $\mathbb Z$, let's say $z_0$, satisfy that $z_0 * r_1 $ belongs to $\mathbb R$ itself.

So is $\mathbb R$ a subspace of $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: IS $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: well, taking just these conditions, $\mathbb{R}$ would be a ‘subspace’ of $\mathbb{Z}$, whatever ‘subspace’ these conditions are describing.

Comment: but for one to be a subspace of other, one doesn't have to be a subset of the other

Comment: @JeremyImmanuel can you give an example?

Comment: @CSquared this very question should be an example if it's proven to be true, which honestly I don't know either.

Comment: The very first, unavoidable condition a set $\;A\;$ must fulfill in order to aspire to be a subspace of a vector space (or whatever space) $\;B\;$ is $\;A\subset B\;$, i.e.: $\;A\;$ *must be* a subset of $\;B\;$ . Besides this, $\;\Bbb R\;$ is a vector space over itself or over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , say...but $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is not a subspace over any field (can you try to prove this?)

Comment: Your three conditions look like the definition of a vector space over a field, though $\mathbb Z$ is a ring rather than a field.  I see nothing in your  conditions related to *sub...*

Comment: assuming from context that you are talking about a vector subspace, if $V$ is a vector space over some field $F$, and $W$ is a subset of $V$, then $W$ is said to be a vector subspace provided that it is also a vector space with respect to the operations of $V$ over the field $F$. whatever conditions you have above do not give a very meaningful definition of subspace.

Comment: Hmm perhaps I misunderstood something then. I'll try to ask my professor again.

Comment: The end result is that you need to go and re-read the definitions.  The punchline is that $\Bbb R$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb Z$, it is not even a subset.  Further... your attempt at listing properties is incorrect as you seem to be treating $\Bbb Z$ as the field as well which was not even mentioned in the question...

Comment: Your third property you mention, "any $z\in \Bbb Z$ and $r\in\Bbb R$ we have that $z\cdot r\in \Bbb R$" is incorrect.  We want any $k\in\Bbb K$ where $\Bbb K$ is the scalar field being used, not $z\in \Bbb Z$... we want for any $k\in\Bbb K$ and $v\in V$ where $V$ is the proposed subspace we have $(k\cdot v)\in V$... which is most often completely different than the proposed parent space.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace):

If $V$ is a vector space over a field $\Bbb K$ **and if $W$ is a subset of $V$**, then $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if under the operations of $V$, $W$ is a vector space over $\Bbb K$. Equivalently, a nonempty **subset** $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if, whenever $w_1, w_2$ are elements of $W$ and $α, β$ are elements of $\Bbb K$, it follows that $αw_1 + βw_2$ is in $W$.

---

In particular, as a part of the definition we have that a subspace of another parent space must specifically be a **subset** of that parent space who satisfies some additional "nice" properties.

$\Bbb R$ fails to be a subset of $\Bbb Z$ and so can not be a **sub**space, regardless what field we were taking this over or what operations were being used.

As to the question of if $\Bbb Z$ might be a subspace of $\Bbb R$, it certainly isn't over any of the standard choices for scalar field and operations since $z\in\Bbb Z$ and $k\in\Bbb K$ we might not have $k\cdot z\in \Bbb Z$, in particular if the scalar field was $\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C$ or similar.  With standard operations for integers as well, [it can be shown that $\Bbb Z$ is never a vector space over any field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/prove-mathbbz-is-not-a-vector-space-over-a-field).  It is feasible that with some exotic operations, one could force it to be a space somehow, but that seems wholly uninteresting to do and invalidates the point of referring to $\Bbb Z$ in the first place if not using the standard operations.